# I need information On SSAS cubes

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

We have tables which have orders detail information but we donot have any primary key columns to create dimensions and facts and their relationships.
How to proceed with this tables to design as SSAS tabular/multidimensional cube

Comment: Please add an example of the data. If your getting the data from a database why are there no keys?

Comment: Hi Jonee,  I need to a develop a cube with data coming from different fact tables and they are teradata tables and they have only primary index columns and they are not primary keys and not unique also.

Comment: And also a way to get unique is to combination of two or more columns.Please need your suggestions for this.

Comment: You need add an example of your data, your index column in your dims, might be the key between dim's and the foreign keys in your fact table.